# Netplan routing failure on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, routing, linux-networking, netplan

I've got the following netplan config in a Ubuntu server 18.04.1:

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
    ens192:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.10.104/27
      dhcp4: false
      routes:
      - metric: 50
        table: 1
        to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.10.126
      routing-policy:
      - from: 192.168.10.104/32
        table: 1
      - table: 1
        to: 192.168.10.104/32
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

Along the following tables:

```
$ cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
1   lan2
```

My requirement is that the server answers to requests in both the dhcp network (ens160) and the statically configured network (ens192) at the same time.

The thing is the configuration does not work once I reboot the server. 
I have no access to the server via anything coming from the static network (ens192) but access via the dhcp interface works without any problems.

But once I do:

```
$ sudo ip link set ens192 down
$ sudo ip link set ens192 up
```

It starts working perfectly.

I've been trying to debug the problem for a while but unsuccessfully, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we  decided to simplify the configuration, no more metrics or the like.

Just something simple like in the documentation:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: true
    ens192:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.10.104/27
      dhcp4: false
      routes:
      - table: 1
        to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 192.168.10.126
      routing-policy:
      - from: 192.168.10.104/27
        table: 1
  renderer: networkd
  version: 2
```

Now both interfaces are correctly configured on startup. No more ip link down/up needed.